# Indefinite INTEGRAL fraction ( irrational )

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{x-1} {1 + \sqrt{x^2+2x-3}}dx$$
The teacher advised me to calculate through Euler's substitution. Please help me to find the integral

(similar topic was created earlier but now I need Euler's substitution using)

Comment: Have you tried the Euler's substitutions?

Comment: $$x^2+2x-3=(x-1)(x+3)$$